# Link of kendo grid under kendo panel is not redirected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, nopcommerce

I am using Nopcommerce 3.4 and it has kendo Panel bar.In which I have Kendo grid.This Kendo grid have two links of Edit and Delete events.but this event is not working.

Razor Page of Kendo Panel bar:

```
 <ul id="panelbar">
        <li>
            General Settings
            <ul>
                <li>
                    @Html.Partial("~/Plugins/PluginName/Views/StoreMapFinder/Tabs/_GeneralSettings.cshtml", Model)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          </ul>
}
@Html.Partial("~/Plugins/PluginName/Views/StoreMapFinder/Tabs/_ResturantGeoCoordinates.cshtml", Model)
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
        expandMode: "multiple"
    });
</script>
```

Partial view of above Panel bar:
_ResturantGeoCoordinates.cshtml has kendo grid in which following Edit event is used and need to redirect.

```
 {
                            field: "Id",
                            title: "@T("Admin.Common.Edit")",
                            width: 100,
                            template: '<a href="/StoreMapFinder/Edit/1">@T("Admin.Common.Edit")</a>'
                        },
```

please Suggest that link is working in grid of panel?
On Page Load Grid is displaying perfectly in panel.see below link
http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010080013L14114477801629648
and after clicking on edit it will display like in below link
http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010080023L14114477801629648

Comment: Can you provide Error message?

Comment: Whenever you not give proper error message here so why we understand your scenario.

Comment: Use link there is no Error message

Comment: can you please make fiddle ?